# Re-install font Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, fonts, dconf

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I installed some packages and the system fonts changed. The characters in the terminal overlap and it makes it difficult to read.

I tried `unity-reset` but that didn't seem to make a difference. I tried resetting dconf using this  `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` as well, but there was no change.

I finally re-installed Unity but I still see the same messed up fonts. I tried to reinstall fonts, but there wasn't much about how to do it.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I tried to install linuxdcpp and ettercap. The issue seemed to start after installing ettercap.

The commands I used to install the packages are:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dev libglademm-2.4-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev g++-3.4 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common g++ libgtkmm-2.4-1 libglademm-2.4-1 scons

sudo apt-get install linuxdcpp    

sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev libpcap0.8-dev  libnet1-dev openssl libssl-dev ncurses-bin libncurses5-dev libnet6-1.3-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev  zlib1g-dev  libltdl-dev pango-graphite pkg-config libpango1.0-dev  libatk1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev

sudo apt-get install ettercap-gtk ettercap-common
```

Comment: Please edit your question to specify which packages you installed and if possible the exact commands you typed to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following.

The fonts are located in `/usr/share/fonts/`. I got the contents of this location from another Ubuntu installation. I deleted the contents of that folder from my computer and copied the files from the other installation.

Then I changed permissions using `sudo chmod 755 -R /usr/share/fonts` and it worked.